# How can I remove tuples containing a specific value from a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

My list of tuples is:

```
[('Huggies', 0.39), ('Snugglers', 0.26), ('Pie', 0.23), ('Baby Love', 0.23)]
```

and i need to remove all tuples that do not contain 0.23.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

To compare every element of the tuple:

```
>>> l = [('Huggies', 0.39), ('Snugglers', 0.26), ('Pie', 0.23), ('Baby Love', 0.23)]
>>> l = [t for t in l if 0.23 in t]
>>> l
[('Pie', 0.23), ('Baby Love', 0.23)]
```

To compare only the second element:

```
>>> l = [('Huggies', 0.39), ('Snugglers', 0.26), ('Pie', 0.23), ('Baby Love', 0.23)]
>>> l = [t for t in l if t[1] == 0.23]
>>> l
[('Pie', 0.23), ('Baby Love', 0.23)]
```

Comment: For completeness: the last `[-1]` ?